# Parse - "Invalid according to Policy: Policy expired." when I try to import a class

Tags: parse-platform

I exported a class and tried to import it again. However, I get this error "Invalid according to Policy: Policy expired.". I tried to import the data to a new class; same error. I am starting with Parse, and I am getting worried of how reliable it can be. This is not doable on a production environment.[image]

Comment: Have you contacted Parse already about this? https://parse.com/help#report

Comment: Well, first thing comes to mind is something I am doing wrong. So I head to the community on Google group and Stackoverflow.

Comment: I tried many times to submit the bug, but the portal doesn't add it. I clicked "Submit" many times with no luck. Even the bug report system has its own bug!.

Comment: Any luck with this issue? @AbdalrahmanShatou

Comment: @TusharGogna Well, I didn't try it again. I am no longer considering Parse as a reliable solution.

Comment: same issue, can't import an exported file